# Create a bootable Windows 8.1 DVD from Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: 16.04, burning

I **don't currently have any OS** in my laptop. I booted it from Ubuntu Live USB. I have a DVD to which I want to burn Windows 8.1 (64-bit) and make it **bootable**. I would like to know, if Ubuntu built in ISO image writer, can burn the Windows 8.1 (64-bit) iso to **bootable**.

If not, are there any alternatives to **burn Windows 8.1 (64-bit) ISO as** **bootable** to a DVD **from Ubuntu Live USB**?

Answer (score 1):

mkusb-nox will build a Windows installer for 7, 8 & 10 64bit.

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/v7

Comment: This is correct. So if you have another USB pendrive, or an adapter, so that you can boot from a memory card, it is a good alternative to use mkusb-nox.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. But it is important that you 'burn an iso image'. (You should *not* create a data DVD with the iso file as file in it.) And it is best to burn at the lowest possible speed to get a reliable result.

There are several tools, that can do this task. I like **k3b**, others are happy with the built-in tool.

**Edit:** You need the Universe repository to install k3b:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

After the installation, *double-click on the iso file's icon* in the file browser, and you should start **k3b's Burn Image window**.

You can also get there by starting k3b via dash.

Comment: How to work with k3b? Could you show me a tutorial?

Comment: k3b is not getting installed in Ubuntu! The Software manager is opening and it is closed when I click on the Install button

Comment: I don't have KDE desktop but Xfce.

Comment: You can also try Brasero. Maybe the main difference is how easy it is to understand the user interface, to push the correct buttons. But I will edit the answer to show how to install k3b (into Ubuntu 16.04.1 live).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ubuntu's default burning application called Brasero.
In the upper menu choose **Burn an ISO image** and select your ISO file.

Brasero is usually the default but can also be installed from repositories if needed.

Any other burning software should work provided the same or equivalent *burn an ISO image* action is selected.